# How do I configure Keyboard layouts using XMonad as my Window Manager?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmonad

So Ubuntu has moved to HAL, and commented out the keyboard section in xorg.conf. So how do I configure keyboard layouts now?

UPD: I'm using XMonad as my window manager, so I need a way to configure layouts that works outside GNOME too.

UPD: Editing xorg.conf *does not* work, here's the relevant section from mine:

```
Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    Option         "XkbOptions" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle, caps:ctrl_modifier, compose:sclk, terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp, grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

Comment: Doesn't this work: Open the Dash and search for 'layout', open the 'Keyboard Layout' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "KeyboardLayout"
    Driver          "evdev"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option          "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
    Option          "XkbOptions" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,caps:ctrl_modifier,compose:sclk,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I chose to configure my keyboard in XMonad.  I tend to shy away from editing the X11 files in XMonad since the Haskell language is so powerful.

In your xmonad.hs file (should be in ~/.xmonad/) I used these two lines to handle keyboard switching via hotkeys in the `additionalKeys` section.

```
-- keyboard layout --
      , ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_d), spawn "setxkbmap -layout dvorak")
      , ((mod1Mask .|. shiftMask, xK_u), spawn "setxkbmap -layout us")
```

Answer (score 2):

[setxkbmap](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2011-September/011796.html) in your `.xinitrc`? More [here](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2011/11/how-to-configure-xmonad-arch-linux.html), including example of setting French layout.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but this is the basic approach i will try. i.e: modifying the xorg.conf files. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Setting_Keyboard_Layout_With_Hot-Plugging
Though, ubuntu seems to use a different xorg folder layout. and you may have trouble finding the right file.

Comment: Modifying xconf.org changes nothing.

Comment: I wanted to add `MatchIsKeyboard        "on"` but made a mistake and wrote `WatchIsKeyboard` and now **the whole system won't boot up!!!!** What the hell, how can Ubuntu devs release a system that can be toasted by a single typo?

Comment: Won't boot?? do you get the bootloader menu? If so, you should be able to drop in to rescue mode and fix the typo...

Comment: Rescue mode won't boot up either :(

Comment: Ok, I fixed the system not booting up (a very hairy trivial issue it was), but your solution still doesn't work: X doesn't recognize MatchIsKeyboard, and without it keyboard options have no effect.